# R: How can I split my data according to type

Tags: r, types

I use R and I have a `data.frame` which contains both numeric and categorical variables. 
TR is the name of my `data.frame`.

I managed to see the output:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(TR)){  print( is.factor(TR[,i])==TRUE )}
```

However, I do not succeed in putting these into a usable output like a vector.:

```
type <-     for(i in 1:ncol(TR)){  print( is.factor(TR[,i])==TRUE )}
```

returns NULL.

Comment: `x == TRUE` is a meaningless operation. Its value is the same as `x`. No need for the `== TRUE` – ever.

Comment: this is for sure something I will keep in my mind! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to `split` your data according to type

```
lst <- lapply(split(colnames(df), sapply(df, class)), function(x) df[x])
```

`list2env` can be used to create multiple objects in the global environment.  But, I would prefer to work within the list

```
 list2env(setNames(lst, paste0('dat', names(lst))), envir=.GlobalEnv)

 head(datfactor,3)
 #  V2
 #1  A
 #2  B
 #3  C
head(datcharacter,3)
 #  V1
 #1  B
 #2  A
 #3  C
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(V1=sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE),
 V2= factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], length.out=10)), V3= rnorm(10), 
 V4=runif(10), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: hey @akrun, this works fine -- and brought up an additional question: Is there an automatic way to generate two separate data.frames: One with the numeric and one with the categorical variables?

Comment: @PikkuKatja You can used `list2env`.  Suppose if there are `character`, `numeric`, and `factor` columns, this will provide separate dataframes based on the class.  Updated the post

Comment: hm, I am not sure do I understand what you did there... where exactly comes the `dat` from? And what does the `paste0` do? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I just had a look at the `?list2env` but that does not make it clearer...

Comment: @PikkuKatja You said you wanted multiple data.frames.  I guess you need separate data.frame objects.  The list element names are `numeric`, `factor`, and `character`.  But, for an object name, this doesn't look very good.  So, I created `datnumeric`, `datfactor` using `paste`, and use `list2env` to create those separate objects.  Another way is to use `?assign`

Comment: Ha, so that part in fact was a beginner question... It took me a few more times to get rid of other stupid mistakes, but now it works very nicely! Thank you also for the working example! This was indeed very helpful. I will also change my accepted answer.

Comment: @PikkuKatja Glad to know that you got something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't ever returning anything to `type`. 
Try `sapply` instead:

```
type <- sapply(1:ncol(TR), function(col.idx) is.factor(TR[,co.idx]))
```